# reflection appears to be losing this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm trying to build an AOP logger for my classes... I'm having an issue where when i reflect back to the targeted function, the function loses access to `this`

so my AOP kinda looks like this

**AOP.js**

```js
class AOP {
  constructor() {

  }
  static ClassHandler(obj) {
    const InstanceHandler = {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        console.log(target.constructor.name);
        const origMethod = target[prop];
        return function (...args) {
          // let result = Reflect.apply(origMethod, this, args)
          let result = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver)
          result = Reflect.apply(result, this, args);
          console.log(prop + JSON.stringify(args)
              + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
          return result;
        };
      },
      apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        console.log('actually applied');
      }
    }

    const handler = {
      construct(target, args) {
        console.log(`${target.name} instantiated`);
        console.log(args);
        const instance = Reflect.construct(...arguments);
        return new Proxy(instance, InstanceHandler);
      }
    }

    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
  }
}

module.exports = AOP;
```

A singleton

**OtherClass.js**

```js
class OtherClass {
  constructor() {
    this._blah = 'this is a shoutout';
  }

  shoutOut() {
    console.log(this._blah);
  }
}

module.exports = new OtherClass();
```

and a class which requires the singleton

**CalculatorDI.js**

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(otherClass) {
    this.otherClass = otherClass;
  }

  add(a, b) {
    this.otherClass.shoutOut();
    return a+b;
  }

  minus(a, b) {
    return a-b;
  }
}

module.exports = Calculator;
```

bringing it all together like this:

```
const AOP = require('./src/aspects/AOP');
const Calculator = AOP.ClassHandler(require('./src/CalculatorDI'));
const otherClass = require('./src/OtherClass');
const calculator = new Calculator(otherClass);

calculator.add(1,1);
```

When running this, I get the error:

> TypeError: this.otherClass.shoutOut is not a function

Comment: `this.otherClass().shoutOut();`

Comment: @JonasW. did you mean to put that? i don't think that's correct?

Comment: Have you tried that?!

Comment: yes... well it gives me a different error now...

Comment: @JonasW. `otherClass` is a class how can you call it without `new`? @Jarede, I think you want `this.otherClass = new otherClass();`. Also, try changing the `apply` to `result = Reflect.apply(result, target, args);`

Comment: @jarede and that is?

Comment: otherClass is a singleton, it already exports itself as `new OtherClass();`

Comment: @MarkMeyer changing to target did the trick.

Comment: Oh thanks @Jarede.  I switched that to make it run as one file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your proxy *always* returns a function, for any property that is accessed, including `this.otherClass`. You will need to use

```
const instanceHandler = {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    console.log(target.constructor.name);
    const orig = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    if (typeof orig == "function") {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return function (...args) {
        const result = orig.apply(this, args);
        console.log(prop + JSON.stringify(args) + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
      };
    } else {
      return orig;
    }
  }
};
```

Also notice that you don't need an `apply` trap in the `instanceHandler`, as none of your instances is a function.

Comment: is there a reason you're doing `orig.apply` rather than `Reflect.apply`?

Comment: @Jarede Mostly because the `apply` has nothing to do with the proxy but is just the usual function decoration.

Comment: So using `Reflect.apply` shouldn't cause issues? I knocked this up https://runkit.com/5a7af2d1bd09580012f31fc2/5b43584ff93f080011766477 and it works with `Reflect.apply` but not with `orig.apply`

Comment: @Jarede Calling it on the `target` instead of the `this` is wrong, that implicitly binds the method.

Comment: So how would i get around the issue within that code sample? your code "looks" like it breaks it, whereas my code returns what i expect.

Comment: @Jarede What is the issue? I can't run your code with the ajv so I don't see what error it throws.

Comment: it's not so much an error, it's more that with your code returns something completely different to the Reflect.apply code.  I'm expecting an object with an errors attribute, when run with your code it seems to return a function or a blank object.

Comment: also i've fixed the runkit code so you just need to comment between the 2 statements.